# Заполнение БД начальными пользователями при использовании EF Core Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть проект ASP.NET MVC Core. Есть подсистема работы с пользователями. По сути стандартный Identity из шаблона проекта, которая создаётся стандартной миграцией.

Вопрос. Как при помощи фреймворка Identity добавить нескольких пользователей при начальном заполнении БД?

Вариант описанный в https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding не подходит, т.к. подразумевает заполнение полей фактически вручную, что не совсем приемлемо (особенно если учесть, что пароль хэшируется).

Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам при помощи [этой статьи](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.12.php).

Создаём класс, который реализует добавление ролей и пользователей.

```
using CustomIdentityApp.Models;  // пространство имен модели User
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomIdentityApp
{
    public class RoleInitializer
    {
        public static async Task InitializeAsync(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            string adminEmail = "admin@gmail.com";
            string password = "_Aa123456";
            if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("admin") == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("admin"));
            }
            if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("employee") == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("employee"));
            }
            if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(adminEmail) == null)
            {
                User admin = new User { Email = adminEmail, UserName = adminEmail };
                IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(admin, password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "admin");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Дорабатываем метод `Main` в `Program.cs`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CustomIdentityApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CustomIdentityApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
                    var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                    await RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(userManager, rolesManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Добавляем в `Startup.cs` метод `AddRoles`.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
```

После всего этого при первом же запуске в БД будут нужные пользователи.